# Carboy Cap vs. Stopper

Tags: equipment, fermentation

Is one better than the other? Why?

Carboy Cap:

[image: Carboy Cap]

http://www.northernbrewer.com/brewing/3-5-6-gall-carboy-cap-orange.html

vs.

Stopper:

[image]

http://www.northernbrewer.com/brewing/no-6-5-drilled-stopper.html

Comment: Caps are nice if you like to keep a thermometer in the beer

Comment: You need to be more specific...better for what?

Comment: Good point. I think I meant general use, nothing specific.

Comment: @joe phillips-  That's one hell of a long thermometer to reach from the cap to the surface of the beer.

Comment: @brewchez Mine reaches -- it's a thermocouple

Comment: @joephillips-  I figured as much, so thanks for clarifying for others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually like the cap.  The reason being is that I feel its better for sanitation.  The carboy cap wraps down and over the edges of the top/neck of the carboy opening.  So after a fermenting session I spray down the cap with sanitizer before I take it off.  The sanitizer drips down the neck of the carboy.  Using a stopper the sanitizer drips down into the crevice between the stopper and the opening of the carboy neck.  Then when you pull the stopper out that stuff drips down into the fermentor.  In theory its sanitized, but its still getting in the fermentor.  Now if your not in the habit of spraying the stopper/cap/neck of your carboy before you open it like I am, then dust and dirt that has fallen into that little crevice is definitely getting into your fermentor and beer.

So I prefer the cap.

For the record though I have several caps and stoppers.  I do use the stoppers on occasion.  But the cap just makes me feel better.

Comment: I only have stoppers, usually the universal ones rather than the solid pictured above. But that is only because I've gotten most of my carboys used.  Brewchez makes an excellent argument for the cap. I'd go with his suggestion.

Comment: I'd disagree about stoppers being unsanitary.  The liquid around the mouth dries and never makes it into the fermenter, and when racking beer out of a carboy you syphon it--it never comes close to touching the mouth.

Comment: @STW  The dried stuff has dried to the stopper and the carboy opening.  When you pull the stopper out it breaks up.  To think none of that gets into the carboy is naive.  I am not saying its a big problem.  I never said they were not sanitary, they are just less sanitary.